# How can I refer to the current dialog scope in continueDialog?

Tags: typescript, botframework

I'm using botframework with botbuilder-solutions but I don't figure out why the `DialogContext` in the method `continueDialog` on a deep nested dialog doesn't refer to the current dialog.

In fact, the first argument in the method of the `continueDialog` in the deepest nested dialog (which extends the class `ComponentDialog`) it always refers to the `DialogContext` of the MainDialog (see the flow below).

For instance, we have this flow of dialogs:

```
- MainDialog (RouterDialog)
                         |--ChildDialog (ComponentDialog)
                                                    |-- ChildChildDialog (ComponentDialog)
```

From the MainDialog which is a `RouterDialog` I add some dialog, like `ChildDialog` and from the `route` method I begin the dialog based on intent.
Until here it works well, because I'm in the ChildDialog as expected.
But if add a new dialog ChildChildDialog in the ChildDialog which extends from `ComponentDialog` in the method `continueDialog`, the `DialogContext` is not referred to current dialog but to MainDialog's dialogset

So, if I would like to create nested dialogs, I have to add each dialog to the main dialog in order to let understand botframework on what dialog ID I'm referring to because otherwise, it is not able to find any dialog with that id.

Is this the right way? Should I continue to register each dialog to the main dialog or there is some good and practical way?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking and what you're trying to do. I'm guessing you're using the `DialogBot` class from the samples and "main dialog" extends `ComponentDialog`. Please make sure you understand that component dialogs have their own dialog sets but you can also create dialog sets on their own. Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog

Comment: I'm sorry for this... I've updated the question

Comment: We can presume you're using the Microsoft Bot Framework from your "botframework" tag, but you've given very little context other than that. What is a `RouterDialog`? If you're using the Virtual Assistant template then that's an enormously important piece of information you've chosen to leave out of your question. You will get better help if you give people all the information necessary to help you. You may find Stack Overflow's asking documents useful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Yes, I thought it was an ininfluent information because my question is strictly related to the Dialogs and nested Dialogs, again, sorry about it. I've just updated the question anyway

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a component dialog's inner dialog set in the following ways:

1. You can call [`ComponentDialog.addDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/componentdialog?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#adddialog-dialog-) to add a dialog to the component dialog's inner dialog set
2. You can call [`ComponentDialog.findDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/componentdialog?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#finddialog-string-) to retrieve a dialog from the component dialog's inner dialog set
3. You can override `onBeginDialog`, `onContinueDialog`, `onEndDialog`, or `onRepromptDialog` to [access an inner dialog context](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/src/componentDialog.ts#L174-L224) created from the inner dialog set

Since you've discovered that `continueDialog` gets passed the outer dialog context I suspect you'll want to override `onContinueDialog` instead.